# compare-object doesn't give any output

Tags: powershell, compareobject

i run

```
$serv1=gwmi -Namespace Root\cimv2 -Class Win32_service
```

i stop some services manually and then run

```
$serv2=gwmi -Namespace Root\cimv2 -Class Win32_service
```

and then i compare these 2 objects

```
compare-object $serv1 $serv2

compare-object -referenceobject $serv1 -differenceobject $serv2
```

both doesn't return any difference however both have some  values different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Compare-Object` compares the Path property of each wmi instance object in the input collections - they will be the same no matter whether the service is running or not.

Use the `-Property` parameter to compare on specific properties, ie.

```
Compare-Object $serv1 $serv2 -Property Name,State
```